# Pass Node.js array from endpoint to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, endpoint

I have a html chart that will display my array from a javascript function 'window.testDataArray'. I would like to replace the sample array with the array data from the server endpoint. I am not sure what I need to do to achieve this.

Client Side

```
window.testDataArray = function(){

        return [6.5,5.2,3.4,5.8] //sample array
    };
```

Updated Client Side(Not Working) I am not sure the syntax is correct here. Any help is very welcome. I am very new to javascript and node.js.

```
window.testDataArray = async function(){
        //      return [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,8,7,4,5,6,1,2,3] 
        try{
        return await fetch('http://localhost:3000/array').then(function (data) { 
            return data 
        }).catch(function(error){return 'testDataArray' + (error)
    });

        }
        catch(error){'Error testDataArray' + error}
    };
```

Server Side

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/array', (req, res) => {
    test()
    async function test (){

    res.send(await local_db.get_data('heights'));//returns array e.g.[5.1,4.3,2.1,5.8] 
    }
    //await local_db.disconnect();
})


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));

//console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/ or http://localhost:3000/");
```

'window.testDataArray' is in utlis.js & is called from 'Line Chart.html'. window.testDataArray fails to get the array from the node.js server endpoint http://localhost:3000/array

**Response to Answers Below  (Unable to reproduce answer locally what am I missing?)**

Thanks for the explanation Emissary your code works like a charm but I cannot get it to work with a local server. I do not intent to have this uploaded to the web. The browser response to the runkit endpoint is `'Cannot GET /'` . But when I navigate to `'http://localhost:3000/array'` I get `[0,10,5,2,20,30,45]`. Please see your code below. I have substituted your runkit endpoint for the local one.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0061)https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/basic.html -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Line Chart</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    <style>

@keyframes chartjs-render-animation{from{opacity:.99}to{opacity:1}}.chartjs-render-monitor{animation:chartjs-render-animation 1ms}.chartjs-size-monitor,.chartjs-size-monitor-expand,.chartjs-size-monitor-shrink{position:absolute;direction:ltr;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;overflow:hidden;pointer-events:none;visibility:hidden;z-index:-1}.chartjs-size-monitor-expand>div{position:absolute;width:1000000px;height:1000000px;left:0;top:0}.chartjs-size-monitor-shrink>div{position:absolute;width:200%;height:200%;left:0;top:0}</style></head>

<body>
    <script>

        const chart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d'), 
    { 
        type: 'line',
        // ... 
    }
)

//const API_HOST = 'https://so-58465005-mqksg0z5tsf8.runkit.sh'
const API_HOST = 'http://localhost:3000'

fetch(`${API_HOST}/array`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => { 
        chart.config.data.labels = Array.from(Array(data.length)).map((_, i) => i + 1)
        chart.config.data.datasets.push({ label: 'my data', data })
        chart.update()
    })

    </script>
</body></html>
```

Please find server side code below. I have substituted '@runkit/runkit/express-endpoint/1.0.0' for 'express'. I must be missing something fundamental here? Thanks again for the help so far.

```js
const express = require("express")
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get("/array", (req, res) => {
    const data = [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
    res.send(JSON.stringify(data))
    res.end();
})


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
``
```

Comment: `fetch('http://localhost:3000/array').then(() => { /* do something */ })` - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I am not getting a value from my function, am I doing anything wrong?                                  window.testDataArray = function(){

       return fetch('http://localhost:3000/array').then((data) => {return data })
    };

Comment: probably this: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Comment: Thanks Emissary for the link, I have amended the code above but am still unable to get an array to my javascript function. Any ideas?

Comment: The issue is that you can't treat an asynchronous call synchronously - `async` / `await` in general is syntactic sugar that allows you to write code imperatively but is still a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) chain under the hood.  Whatever is using `testDataArray()` in your code needs to be restructured in a way where it does not expect an immediate result.  Can you include enough client code for an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have uploaded the sample files as a zip. See the link above. I should see two lines plotted when the array reads in correctly. I have tried a few bits of code but it either breaks the chart or does not plot the second line as there is no array passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your project, I've replicated your [server on RunKit](https://runkit.com/mylesj/so-58465005) - please take note of two important components to this:

- composite object types cannot be returned without serialising them on the server side and deserialising them in the client - HTTP data is transmitted as plain text - this is commonly done via [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).
- it isn't clear where you are serving the `.html` file from but looks likely that you'll be running into cross-origin errors - I included middleware to handle this, [further reading into CORS available here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

To address the problem described in the question, you are currently trying to statically apply the data to the configuration before a request has responded. Instead try reacting to the data in the promise returned by `fetch`.

Forgetting `async` / `await` for now, this can be achieved by passing a callback function to `.then` - similar to how you are already responding to button click-events elsewhere in your attached example.

```js
const chart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d'), 
    { 
        type: 'line',
        // ... 
    }
)

const API_HOST = 'https://so-58465005-mqksg0z5tsf8.runkit.sh'

fetch(`${API_HOST}/array`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => { 
        chart.config.data.labels = Array.from(Array(data.length)).map((_, i) => i + 1)
        chart.config.data.datasets.push({ label: 'my data', data })
        chart.update()
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: This works great from your runkit endpoint but I am unable to reproduce this locally. What am I doing wrong? See amended post above. Many thanks.

Comment: `exports` is part of the RunKit API, try remove it from `const app = express()`. You're also now requesting `http://localhost:3000/array/array` in the edited code.

Comment: Thank you!! It now works, I have updated the code above to remove my typo.